# Android: Disallow user to select cursor position in EditText?

Tags: java, android

Right now I use onFocusListener to automatically move the cursor to the end of the EditText string. This works fine when the box is being Focused, however, once focused if the user taps a position in the string, the cursor moves there. I've tried implementing other methods in addition to the Focus (Touch, Click) when I do, the cursor moves briefly to the end but then quickly to where the user clicked. Is there a way I can prevent the user from clicking the cursor position and have it automatically setSelection(EditText.getText().length())?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.sb.skeleton;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;

/**
 * @author rajesh
 *
 */
public class SBEditText extends EditText {

    /**
     * @param context
     */
    public SBEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     */
    public SBEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     * @param defStyle
     */
    public SBEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelection(int start, int stop) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(SkeletonAppActivity.TOSS, "setSelection");
        super.setSelection(start, stop);
    }


    @Override
    public void setSelection(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(SkeletonAppActivity.TOSS, "selectionChanged");
        super.setSelection(index);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        setSelection(getText().length());
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

}
```

> This class ensure that when ever a change happened for the EditText
>   content it will set the cursor to the end of the text.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what I needed! Thank you very much, worked perfectly.

Comment: I don't know why I get classCast Exception !

Comment: This worked for me as well. But can you explain why override the onDraw method rather than overriding

Comment: onDraw will be called as soon as the text content changed for the text view, and also when the user move the cursor back and forth this will give a quick feel  that the cursor is always at the end of the view. There can be other methods which would give you the same result but need to look in to this.